# Xamarin Forms Error after updating to windows 10 and installing visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

MSB4062 The "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlGTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\Admin.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\3.0.0.482510\build\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Is there any solution to get rid of this error

Answer (score 1):

Clean your project,
Close the project,
Delete files in prefetch, temp and %temp% ,
Reopen the project ,
Rebuild the project,

If above step does not solve the problem then ensure if the NuGet package of xamarin forms installed for all the projects is of the same version (.net standard, Android and iOS).

Answer (score 1):

Finally got a solution. After downgrading the Xamarin.Forms from version 3.0.0.482510 to version 2.5.1.527436 in all the projects, it compiled without errors.

Comment: xamarin.forms 3.0 uses .net standard 2.0, no longer PCL

Comment: also make sure you use Windows 10 v1709 or 1803, older versions like 1607, 1703 are not .net standard 2.0 compatible.

Comment: Am using windows 10 v1709 but still I have the same problem. What is the actual cause of the issue

Comment: make sure you shared lib is .net standard 2.0 lib and if you use UWP, set min Version to 16299